# How to change some text inside the object in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
data = [
  { title: "02/01/2019 - [Juan] - D - [Leo]", score: 72 },
  { title: "02/01/2019 - [Carlo] - N - [Trish]", score: 92 }
];
```

What I'm trying to do here is the change the text in the title which has `- N -` or `- D -`

it should be like this:

```js
[
  { title: "02/01/2019 - [Juan] - Day - [Leo]", score: 72 },
  { title: "02/01/2019 - [Carlo] - Night - [Trish]", score: 92 }
];
```

Comment: Can be done using regex..post what you tried

Comment: @NightKing angular

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I tried to use the ```split('- D -', 2)``` but it remove the ```- D -```

Comment: have you tried replacing where you have "D" and "N" by using the replace function

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava its an array, how it will determine it its ```- D -``` or ```- N -```

Comment: You loop through it and run the `replace` on the `title` property of each object

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava is it okay to create an sample on stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const data = [
  { title: "02/01/2019 - [Juan] - D - [Leo]", score: 72 },
  { title: "02/01/2019 - [Carlo] - N - [Trish]", score: 92 },
  { title: "02/01/2019 - [Danny] - N - [Darko]", score: 32 },
  { title: "02/01/2019 - [Django] - D - [Unchained]", score: 62 }
],
result = data.map(obj => {
  const temp = { ...obj }, { title } = temp

  if(title.match(/- D -/g)) temp.title = title.replace(/- D -/g, '- Day -')
  else if(title.match(/- N -/g)) temp.title = title.replace(/- N -/g, '- Night -')
    
  return temp
})

console.log(result)
console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{ min-height: 100%; }
```